# tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup ONLY in SPYDER IDE

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, spyder, eager

I have tried to perform an eager execution of a simple code.

I've tried it on both Jupyter Notebook and Spyder IDE.
With Jupyter I have no problem but when I execute the code in Spyder it returns an error:

```
File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5496, in enable_eager_execution "tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup.")
ValueError: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup.
```

and the code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution ()
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
def square (x):
     return tf.multiply (x, x)

grad = tfe.gradients_function (square)

print (grad (3.))
```

Comment: can you try resetting spyder then running it again?

python spyder --reset

Comment: No, I've tried it and it's the solution. Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type `Command + .` (on Mac), or `Ctrl + .` (on Windows) to restart your Spyder kernel.

Comment: No, I've tried it and it's the solution. Many thanks